# Avoid Directory listing in a shared server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using shared server for my website and therefore i dnt have access to my  httpd.conf.

my director r getting listed like

when i click on mysite.com/xyz/

all php files are showing.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .htaccess file add

```
Options -Indexes
```

To follow up and more thoroughness, you can also use an index file in the directory by creating a blank `index.html` file.

```
e.g. index.html
```

Or you can also specify the exact file and orders you want to be the index in htaccess with

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

So there you have a few choices. The file will have to exist and it can contain anything or nothing.

Comment: Some hosts no longer permit the `Options` command. If that includes your host, you have a couple of choices. 1) make a dummy index.html (an index file specified in the `DirectoryIndex` command) in the directory(ies) to protect. It can be empty or just say "Hey, you lookin' at _me_?" :) Choice 2) is to add a new index type to `DirectoryIndex` in .htaccess (e.g., "/noIndex.html") to do the same thing (display a snide remark to snoopers).

Comment: @PhilPerry Yes that maybe true depending on the host.